# Average of four dates with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula

I have two Excel sheets. Sheet 1 has the following records:

```
Salon          coach       date         amount
Sal1           col1       11/7/2018     500
Sal1           col1       11/1/2018     400
Sal1           col1       10/25/2018    600
Sal1           col1       10/19/2018    700
Sal1           col1       10/1/2018     250
And so on
```

Sheet 2 has the following cloumns and records:

```
Salon         coach       average of lastest 4 dates
Sal1          col1                       ???
```

I want to find the average amount for the four latest dates excluding the most recent date. Calculation should start from 2nd latest date to 5th latest date with matching the criteria salon and coach.

[image]

Comment: Thanks dear for the editing

Comment: Those dates, are they in a random order? Or can we assume it's reverse chronological order starting top row going down?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. These can be in random as well as in chronological order

Comment: If chronological order is necessary, i can sort these dates from newest to oldest

Comment: Are you sure there always be **at least** 4 dates for each Salon ?

Comment: @Dani Hi, could you update/fine-tune your question with the comment you made on the answer of MichalRosa ? My own answer is for the original question (average for last 4 dates), but it seems you actually want the average of the 2nd last date until the 4th last? So does that mean the average of 3 values? Or of 4 values (from 2nd last until 5th last)?

Comment: I am really sorry for the confusion caused by my question. Yes Michal's answer worked for my original post then i asked again in the comments and it is not necessary that it should have atleast 4 or 5 dates, number of dates can be more or less but if dates are less than 5 then i will ignore those records. dates atleast should be 5 to calculate this. i hope i cleared y question

Comment: @Dani That's fine, it is natural that a question evolves. I updated my answer, and made it flexible (with two parameters), so you can use the same formula to calculate different variations for your analysis.

Comment: @Peter K Yeah i included and it works like a charm. Thank you so much for all the help and support.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer with some explanation. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah it helped a lot, this even only not resolved my problem but also gave me clarification. Salute to your Sir.

Comment: Ok thanks. If your question was fully answered, please do not forget to "close" the topic by accepting the answer that was most helpful / best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Final Version** (flexible date parameters & defined names)

With an array function (so you have to enter this with ctrl+shift+enter), and with named ranges to make the formula better understandable :

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(
     (r_salon=A14)*
     (r_coach=B14)*
     (r_date>=LARGE(IF((r_salon=A14)*(r_coach=B14);r_date;);
                    MIN(d_last;COUNTIFS(r_salon;A14;r_coach;B14))))*
     (r_date<=LARGE(IF((r_salon=A14)*(r_coach=B14);r_date;);
                    MIN(d_first;COUNTIFS(r_salon;A14;r_coach;B14))));
      r_amount))}
```

For testing, I put the formula on the same sheet as the data, so Sal1 is in cell `A14` and col1 in cell `B14`.

Explanation of the formula (so you can fine-tune if needed) :

- The two inner `IF` create an array of all dates for Sal1 and col1 (cells `A14` and `B14`), and the `LARGE` functions around it takes the n-th largest value; the n is actually calculated as the minimum of `d_first` or `d_last` respectively *and* the number of dates/rows actually present for the sal1/col1 combination (this will take care of the case that for some Salon/Coach combination(s) there could be less than `d_first` or `d_last` dates;
- The outer `IF` then creates an array of all dates that meet all criteria, i.e. for Sal1 *AND* col1 *AND* that are after `d_first` *AND* before `d_last` (calculated with the inner `IF` in the previous step); The `*` is shorthand for the `AND` operator, which also works for array formula's (the `AND` doesn't);
- The `AVERAGE` is trivial of course.

To make the formula more flexible, I used two parameter (defined names): `d_first` is the most recent date you want to include, and `d_last` is the last date you want to include. Some examples:

- `d_first=2` and `d_last=5` : to answer your actual (updated) question, i.e. average for 4 dates, starting with the 2nd most recent until the 5th most recent;
- `d_first=1` and `d_last=4` : this is the same as the first version of the answer, i.e. the result will be the average of the 4 most recent dates;
- `d_first=2` and `d_last=4` : this will be the average of the 2nd most recent date until the 4th;
- `d_first=1` and `d_last=1` : this will just result in the most recent date (average of one value is just the value itself).

You just have to make sure that `d_first` is a positive integer (greater than zero), and `d_last` must be greater or equal than `d_first`. If they are greater than the total number of dates in the data-set, the result is the value corresponding with the earliest date.

You also have to think about what happens if you have multiple entries for the same date. The current formula works with cut-off dates (earliest and latest), and not with number of records to actually average ((if you have several records with the same date that is within the cut-off dates, all these will be used in the calculation of the average).

**Version 2** (adding more flexibility)

The formula :

`{=AVERAGE(IF(($A$2:$A$11=A14)*($B$2:$B$11=B14)*($C$2:$C$11>=LARGE(IF(($A$2:$A$11=A14)*($B$2:$B$11=B14);$C$2:$C$11;);MIN(d_last;COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11;A14;$B$2:$B$11;B14))))*($C$2:$C$11<=LARGE(IF(($A$2:$A$11=A14)*($B$2:$B$11=B14);$C$2:$C$11;);MIN(d_first;COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11;A14;$B$2:$B$11;B14))));$D$2:$D$11))}`

**Version 1** (original question, i.e. avg of last 4 dates; this is not relevant, as the question has been updated)

You can accomplish that with the following array formula (so you have to enter this with ctrl+shift+enter):

`{=AVERAGE(IF(($A$2:$A$11=A14)*($B$2:$B$11=B14)*($C$2:$C$11>=LARGE(IF(($A$2:$A$11=A14)*($B$2:$B$11=B14);$C$2:$C$11;);MIN(4;COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11;A14;$B$2:$B$11;B14))));$D$2:$D$11))}`

**Note**
(*just FYI, and in case you debug the formula with F9 and inspect the various array intermediate results*)
The arrays not only contains the values that meet the condition(s), but will be the same size than the argument of the `IF` (i.e. will have as many values as there are rows in your data set), and is filled with `FALSE` for the rows that do not match the condition(s). As the `AVERAGE` function (like many others) does not take into account the `FALSE` values, this has no impact on the result, hence I did not make the formula overly complex to keep only the matching dates in the arrays.

Comment: Sorry to say but it doesn't work for multiple Salon/coach combinations the same reason my first solutions were wrong.  You have to create separate date arrays for each combination.

Comment: @MichalRosa Did you test the formula, and if so, what is wrong with the result? With my solution, the data arrays are calculated dynamically within the formula, so do not need to be created separately. This formula works for all possible combinations of Salon and Coach, so I am not sure why it does not work for you?

Comment: I have tested it.  Please try it yourself with multiple Salons and Coaches - use an input table as shown in my answer.  You have to check dates for each Salon/Coach combination separately.  Have a look at the screenshot - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iTftH_8nEeB7oD1ZzniMDYjiZek0wlsO - values in column E are calculated mannualy, values in column I are from my formula, values in column J come from your formula.  Cheers, Michal

Comment: But my formula is still answering the original question, i.e. average of last 4 dates, and I read in the comments from @Dani under your answer (and also what you wrote in the screenshot in you answer) that you calculate "previous 4 without the last one" ?

Comment: Peter, your formula works only if there is one combination of Salon/Coach, it fails if there are more.  It's that simple. It answers the original problem as posed but not the extended problem presented later. Please do check it yourself.  Cheers, Michal

Comment: My formula must be put in place of the question marks in the original question, i.e. next to Sal1 and col1, and it takes these two values as input and gives the result. The formula needs then of course to be copied down, and will work for any combination of Salon/Coach that will be put next to the formula (and for which input data is available!). This is indeed not explicitly explained in my answer.

Comment: Peter, please have a look at this - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yII_gYF_G21VX7X12bTPTSTEEDDMy5sU it's a spreadsheet with your formula calculating a table with multiple combinations of Salon/Coach.  Your formula is in column J, mine is in column I.  Please study it.  Regards, Michal

Comment: Michal, you made a mistake in changing the references of the IFs: you have `($B$2:$B$16=G3)` but it should be `($A$2:$A$16=G3)`. The result will still be different than yours, because we are calculating different things (see one of my previous comments). If you use the Version 2 of my solution, this will give you full control over the range of dates to average.

Comment: Here is your spreadsheet back, corrected and with v2 of the formula (and with parameters set to duplicate your calculation) : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2e5d1203be422fe4c489508f1c8019d720181109005506/388d89

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Well, this one should work.  I hope I've tested it for all possible scenarios.

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(
 (Table1[Salon]=G5)*(Table1[coach]=H5)*
 (Table1[date]>=LARGE(((Table1[Salon]=G5)*(Table1[coach]=H5)*(Table1[date])),5))*
 (Table1[date]<=LARGE(((Table1[Salon]=G5)*(Table1[coach]=H5)*(Table1[date])),2))*
 Table1[amount])/4
```

Let me know how it works for you.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks michal, can i also have solution if i want to start with 2nd lastest date down to 4?

Comment: Welcome.

     =SUMPRODUCT((salon=F2)*(coach=G2)*(date>=LARGE(date,4))*(date<=LARGE(date,2))*amount)/3

Comment: Main purpose behide this is that i want to calculate % of change between the amount of lastest date to average of prevoius 4 latest date, so that is why i need average amount of 4 latest date excluding the latest date.

Comment: Just change the number in date>=LARGE(date,4) and (date<=LARGE(date,2) as required.  Cheers,

Comment: Yeah i have change but this is giving me correct values when i use range and when i use table column it doesn't give me correct value. Please see below my formula: =SUMPRODUCT((SalonInput[Salon]='Per Change'!A2)*(SalonInput[Coach]='Per Change'!B2)*(SalonInput[Week Ending]>=LARGE(SalonInput[Week Ending],5))*(SalonInput[Week Ending]<=LARGE(SalonInput[Week Ending],2))*SalonInput[Weekly Takings])/4

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(
(Table1[Salon]=F2)*
(Table1[coach]=G2)*
(Table1[date]>=LARGE(Table1[date],5))*
(Table1[date]<=LARGE(Table1[date],2))*
Table1[amount])/4

You seem to have it right, I've checked the calculations and as far as I can see they are correct.  What results do you get from your input which seem to be wrong?  Cheers,

Comment: Dear Your Solution works if we have one salon type and one Coach type for example i have list of salons and Coaches and i don't want to change ranges separately for  every salon just say the same range is not working for Sal2 col2.

Comment: I have added image in original question please see that for clarification

Comment: @ Michal, Your formula works like a charm and thank you for all the help and support